# Millisecond timestamp => ISO date is off by 1 millisecond

Tags: ruby, time

I have a timestamp in milliseconds I want to convert to an ISO date string in UTC:

```rb
require 'time'

timestamp = 1534442471123

puts Time.at(timestamp / 1000.0).utc.strftime('%FT%T.%3NZ')
```

which outputs:

```
2018-08-16T18:01:11.122Z
```

Why is it off by 1 millisecond (`...122Z`, not `...123Z`)?

Is that because of floating point numbers memory representation issues?

Comment: The [usual definition of floating point](http://employees.oneonta.edu/zhangs/csci201/IEEE%20Floating%20Point%20Format.htm) represents the exponent to the base 2. Hence you can't reliably devide by 1000. If you just calculate some `x/1000.0` and print the result, you may not notice an error, because it is compensated during rounding/formatting. Avoid floating point arithmetic if you need precise results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `Float` inaccuracies of which you are already aware are playing a role here, it's ultimately the “fault” of the `%N` conversion specifier which wants to prevent you from traveling into the future. [From the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

> ```
>   The digits under the specified length are truncated to avoid
>   carry up.
> ```

Other conversions (like `sprintf` with `'%.3f'`) would've rounded up in this case. So your `Time` object's milliseconds aren't actually `123` but `122.9???` which due to `%3N` becomes `122`. To handle (sub-)seconds precisely `Time` supports integers and rational numbers:

```
Time.at(*timestamp.divmod(1000), :millisecond, in: 'utc')
# or
Time.at(Rational(timestamp, 1000), in: 'utc')
Time.at(timestamp / 1000r, in: 'utc')
```